# For the un-finished 3-way TCP handshake, why the windows OS report the FD_ACCEPT event to the application

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp

**Test Scenario**

I had written a windows program which I simply called it "simpleServer.exe". This program is just a simulation of a very basic server application. It listens on a port, and wait for incoming messages. The listening Socket was defined to be a TCP Stream Socket. that's all that this program is doing.

I had been deploying this exact same program on 2 different machines, both running on windows 7 professional 64bit. This machine will act as a host. and they are stationed in the same network area.

then, using the program "nmap", I used another machine on the same network, to act as a client. using the "-sS" parameter on "nmap", I do a Syn Scan, to the IP and Port of the listening simpleServer on both machine (one attempt at a time).

(note that the 2 hosts already had "wireshark" started, and is monitoring on tcp packets from the client's IP and to the listening port.)

In the "wireshark" entry, on both machine, I saw the expected tcp packet for Syn Scan:

```
client ----(SYN)----> host

client <--(SYN/ACK)-- host

client ----(RST)----> host
```

the above packet exchange suggests that the connection was not established.

But on the "simpleServer.exe", only one of it had "new incoming connection" printed in the logs, while the other instance was not alerted of any new incoming connection, hence no logs at all.

**Code Snippets**

```
iRetVal = WSAEventSelect (m_Socket, m_hSocketEvent, FD_ACCEPT);
if (SOCKET_ERROR == iRetVal)
{
    if (WSAGetLastError()==WSAENOTSOCK)
    {
        return E_SOCKET_INVALID;
    }

    CHKLOGGER (m_pLogger->Log (LOGGER_LOG_ERROR,"GHLSocket::OnAccept() Error while WSAEventSelect(). Error code: ", WSAGetLastError() ));
    #if defined GHLSOCKET_DEBUG_VERSION
        printf ("Error while WSAEventSelect(). Error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    #endif
    return E_FAILED_RECV_DATA;
}

// Wait for Network Events to occcur
dwRetVal = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents (   1,
                                        &m_hSocketEvent,
                                        FALSE,
                                        lTimeout,
                                        TRUE);

if ( WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT == dwRetVal )
{
    return E_TIMEOUT;
    goto CleanUp;
}

if ( WSA_WAIT_FAILED == dwRetVal)
{
    CHKLOGGER (m_pLogger->Log (LOGGER_LOG_ERROR,"GHLSocket::OnAccept() WSAWaitForMultipleEvents() failed. Error code: ", WSAGetLastError() ));
    #if defined GHLSOCKET_DEBUG_VERSION
        printf ("Error in WSAWaitForMultipleEvents() failed. Error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    #endif
    dwReturn = E_FAILED_RECV_DATA;
    goto CleanUp;
}

// Parse the Results from the Network Events.
iRetVal = WSAEnumNetworkEvents (m_Socket, m_hSocketEvent, &mEvents);
if (SOCKET_ERROR == iRetVal)
{
    CHKLOGGER (m_pLogger->Log (LOGGER_LOG_ERROR,"GHLSocket::OnAccept() Error while WSAEnumNetworkEvents(). Error code: ", WSAGetLastError() ));
    #if defined GHLSOCKET_DEBUG_VERSION
        printf ("Error while WSAEnumNetworkEvents(). Error code: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    #endif
    dwReturn =  E_FAILED_RECV_DATA;
    goto CleanUp;
}

// ACCEPT event Detected.
if (mEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT)
{
    // Perform accept operation.
    *p_SOCKET = accept (m_Socket, NULL,NULL);
}
```

**Help That I Needed**

why is the different behavior from the 2 same of the same application on a different machine with the same OS?

Comment: Why is client sending RST on SYN-ACK from server?

Comment: @Prabhu Most likely to play nice without making the port scan too complicated. If you send nothing you have a lingering session on the server, but handling the full TCP socket establishment + close might not be fast enough for port-scan, hence reset.

Comment: @OP it feels like this is more an OS question that belongs on superuser. But knowing windows and networking apps, take a look at windows firewall settings.

Comment: @Prabhu in our production, the client is F5 for Traffic Management, the F5 sent the use the 3-way TCP handshake to check the port is alive or not

Comment: @KillianDS, can you give me some suggestion that how to handle it, i am a freshman on the windows networking progress.

Comment: Can anyone give me more advice?